# Django ModelMultipleChoiceField lazy loading of related m2m objects

Tags: python, django, django-admin, many-to-many

I tried to use `django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField` in one of the model's admin page in order to update `m2m` relation through form. I also specified `django.contrib.admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple` as a widget for form's field and achieved my purpose successfully. The problem is, since I have over 10K related objects, all of them are included as an option in form page and that makes page very severely slow. For illustrating this problem I am adding here analogy of this case's appliance on `django.contrib.auth.models.Group` model and related 'users'.

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

from forms import GroupAdminForm

admin.site.unregister(Group)  # get rid of default one


class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = GroupAdminForm
    filter_horizontal = ['permissions']

admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


User = get_user_model()


class GroupAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        exclude = []

    users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
         queryset=User.objects.all(),
         required=False,
         widget=FilteredSelectMultiple('users', False)
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GroupAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['users'].initial = self.instance.user_set.all()

    def save_m2m(self):
        self.instance.user_set.set(self.cleaned_data['users'])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(GroupAdminForm, self).save()
        self.save_m2m()
        return instance
```

In the codes above, default admin change page for `Group` is disabled and implemented again that also includes input for group users. This is how it looks after I added 1000 test user objects:[image]

As you see, all of 1000 users are included as an option. My question is that, how can I achieve to disable displaying them initially and display as the user types something in filter box?

**Note:** Please don't suggest me to use `admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields`, since that is not user-friendly. Also, it would be better to solve this issue without help of any third-party package.

Comment: I've got the same problem - did you find a solution?

Comment: @HenryM I just changed `queryset=User.objects.all()` to `queryset=User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)` in `ModelMultipleChoiceField`. If you need all users, you can use [django-ajax-selects](https://django-ajax-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).